# Entity Framework 4.1 Foreign Key Mapping with conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

First the database already exists, assume also that changing the type is not an option.

```
Table CaseTypes
tinyint ID
varchar(xx) description

Table Case
int ID
int Type  (foreign key to CaseTypes.ID but not defined in database)

public partial class CaseType
{
   public byte ID { get; set; } ......


   public partial class Case
{
  [ForeignKey("Type")]
  public virtual CaseType CType { get; set; }  
  public int Type { get; set;}
}.......
```

Using entity framework how can I map these.  I've tried using a [NotMapped] property, didn't work.

Hopefully my issue is clear, let me know if not.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you mean that you want to keep `Type` out of the mapping or would you rather have EF use it in an association even though it's not a database-defined foreign key? And, this code-first, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe its possible in Entity Framework, as the designer will pick this up and not build.

The only way I can think around this is to duplicate the value as an extra column. Then delete the property from the EDMX Designer. This way the user won't see the property, but they'll still be able to navigate to the other table.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this wouldn't be possible but figured I should ask since my ef skills are still beginner.